Linked font-family not showing up in .css File
The .css file is not recognizing the linked font-family at all, as you can see in the image that I'll add the new font-family is not in the list. Is there a way to fix this or is it something wrong that I'm doing? I'll link two pictures of the files. .html File .css file I'm using the embed code option in the fonts google webpage.
I tried changing to another font-family and it didn't worked. I was expecting the linked font-family to show up in the list.

The CSS Screenshot simply shows the Autocomplete/Intellisense of your IDE. This does not include external fonts loaded via Google Fonts. Just because your desired font is not listed there, doesn't mean you can write it yourself font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
